# Why does my wine application not display in the dash properly?

Tags: unity, gnome

Here is my .desktop file for Civ 4:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Civilization 4 - Beyond the Sword
#Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/cornwall/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/cornwall/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Firaxis\\ Games/Sid\\ Meier\\'s\\ Civilization\\ 4\\ -\\ Beyond\\ the\\ Sword/Sid\\ Meier\\'s\\ Civilization\\ 4\\ -\\ Beyond\\ the\\ Sword.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/cornwall/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix "/home/cornwall/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start Menu/Programs/Firaxis Games/Sid Meier's Civilization 4 - Beyond the Sword/Sid Meier's Civilization 4 - Beyond the Sword.lnk"
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/cornwall/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Firaxis Games/Sid Meier's Civilization 4/Beyond the Sword
Icon=/home/cornwall/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Firaxis Games/Sid Meier's Civilization 4/Beyond the Sword/Assets/res/Civ4BtS.ico
```

The commented out line is the original Exec line. I ran desktop-file-validator and it notified me of the quotation mark in "Meier's" to be false. I fixed that in the line below the commented one. The validator does not output any other errors now. However, all I get is this:

[image: problem]

I could live without the title showing but Unity also won't let me pin it to the dash (while other properly generated wine programs can be).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Displays fine here. Is the .desktop file in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory?

Comment: See my answer. You helped me fix it. If you want answer points, write it up and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jacob Johan Edwards, I noticed that the path to the .desktop file also contained "sid meier's" in the name. The apostrophe symbol apparently makes the parser unhappy and mangled the entry as a result. I just renamed the install directory and renamed the .desktop entry in ~/.local/share/applications. Thanks so much for the help.